# Meshes turning white during rendering

Tags: rendering, mesh, materials

I'm finished my model and would like to render it:

[image]

However when I render, there are some issues:

[image]

Some sections are coming out white where they should be grey / black. Other bits are black where the meshes intersect.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may set different colors in the materials that show up temporarily in the *3D Viewport*, but the materials with the names

- asphalt
- Material
- sidewalk
- sidewalk.001
- store-front

all have a keyframe on the *Base Color* of the *Principled BSDF* at frame #37, setting it to white. Before rendering, Blender evaluates keyframe settings and shows the determined color, not the one you've set afterwards and not stored in a keyframe.

I would delete all those keyframes unless you want to animate changing colors (but then the other colors need keyframes, too).

[image]

For the black intersections: overlapping faces cause problems in rendering. You shouldn't have two or more faces in the same location.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! No idea how I set the keyframe value

Comment: @TomSelleck I don't know either, but it's quite simple  Just be over the color field with your mouse, then hit I to insert... and then you probably duplicated the material which had the keyframe.

Answer (score 1):

Edit :
@Gordon Brinkman is right, I didn't saw that but yeah, you've got a keyframe on the color.

First, it appears that your asphalt shader is white.
[image: asphalt shader]

Second, the angle that are "black" are due to an error while modeling. Your mesh has overlapping faces causing these black artifacts. You should remodel it without overlapping.

Comment: It is white, but simply setting a different color will not help - see my answer.